# Datagridview freeze when scroll bar appear

Tags: c#

I have a datagrid view written in c# language. My application works fine. But whenever I load data to the gridview, the vertical gridview scroll bar get freeze and not functioning. I cant scroll the gridview unless using my mouse scroll. Any advise please?

Here's my gridview codes:

```
void Add(string m)
    {
        List<string>[] list;
        list = dbConnect.Select(m);
        //dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count; i++)
        {
            int number = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = list[0][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[1].Value = list[1][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[2].Value = list[2][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[3].Value = list[3][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[4].Value = list[4][i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[number].Cells[5].Value = list[5][i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us some part of your code.

Comment: @jomsk1e have edited the question with code,please advise.

Comment: Just a thought, why not work with a data source instead of manually adding data?

Comment: @o_weisman Im using express edition,not able to connect to mysql datasource. can you help me with this prob?my gridview got freeze if the scrollbar enable.

Comment: Is this done in a different thread than the GUI thread?

Comment: @o_weisman sorry im new in this,can you guide me more?i dont get the question.

Comment: Check out answer #14 here: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/datagridview-scrollbar-bug-66978.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51169/discussion-between-o-weisman-and-ren)

Comment: @Ren where is the Add function called from?